# Using gets.chomp.downcase in initialize method in ruby. Test failing in TDD

Tags: ruby, tdd

I am trying to create a test and some code. My test is failing and I don't know why.

This is my test:

```
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/pride'

require_relative '../lib/guess_evaluator'

class GuessProcessor < Minitest::Test
  def test_right_length
    player_guess = Guess.new
    assert_equal 4, player_guess.user_answer.size
  end
```

This is my actual code:

```
class Guess

  attr_reader :user_answer

  def initialize(user_answer = gets.chomp.downcase)
    @user_answer = user_answer
  end
```

When I run my test, I don't get an opportunity to input my response when my code creates a new Guess object. Shouldn't gets.chomp.downcase get called? Why or why not? When I run my minitest, it fails and I don't have a chance to give in input.

Answer (score 0):

We expect the tdd test always tests the same cases. Then, you can modify your code with confidence, because the tests you write are still passing. At tdd testing you don't enter manualy any data.

Then, just change `player_guess = Guess.new` with `player_guess = Guess.new('aaaa')` and the test should pass.